# Missing right and bottom borders in Chrome (full-screen mode)

Tags: html, css

Please advise why Chrome (Linux OS) doesn't show right and bottom red border lines in full-screen mode for generic page with applied css reset.

```
body,
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[image]
[image]

At the same time it shows them in window mode?
I also checked the same page in Firefox and it shows borders as expected whatever mode is being used.

https://codepen.io/vadim-lo/full/vYGKzZP

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is `100% + (1px left-border) + (1px right-border) = 100% + 2px` which is more then `100%`

You can "include" padding and borders to the total width of an element  just add

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

**Note**  this rule will be applied to every element because of the `*`

in your case

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

might be enough (most people though want to use the `*` because then they never have to worry for this again)

See [CSS box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) for more information

Comment: but why it shows border in window mode? and why Firefox shows borders? also i tried to modify css as per your proposal by adding box-sizing property, but Chrome still doesn't show right and bottom borders

Comment: @user947668 not 100% sure but it could also be because 100% is not a fixed width. so depending on screen resolution and browser (render engine) there might be a tiny bit of space left to eighter show or not show the border.